Match a constructor with a spotbugs filter file
A Spotbugs filter file can be specific at matching a method.
Is it possible to restrict the filter to bugs associated with a constructor? For a class Boo I tried already <Method name="Boo"/> and <Method name="new"/>, just guessing, but those don't work.
To be more specific, the constructor is

EI_EXPOSE_REP2: may expose internal representation by storing an externally mutable object

and I want to suppress this specifically for the constructor and not for a setter.

To match a constructor in a Spotbugs filter file, we can use
<Method name="&lt;init>" />

This uses the class file internal name <init> for constructors.
The rule matches all constructors. I did not try, but as for normal methods, the params attribute should allow to discriminate between different constructors, if necessary.
